# how can set tool bar items in appdelegate for ViewController?

Tags: iphone

i am using Following  code in appdelegate.m file..but it did not work..?

```
      OthersController *mm_OthersController = [[OthersController alloc] init];
      [mm_OthersController tScreen];
   [mm_OthersController release];
```

when i put break point, it goes to the function  tScreen correctly....but i can get output..?**if i call the method "tScreen" from view willappear of OthersController, it works fine....**
the method in OthersController.m file

```
 -(void)tScreen
{

 [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden: NO animated: NO];

 self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
}
```

any help pls......?

Comment: I recommend that you Google "iphone uitoolbar example" or "iphone uitoolbar tutorial". You'll learn more going through some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether you are doing this after adding the navigation controller to your window or before it.

Follow it like this:

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

 OthersController *mm_OthersController = [[OthersController alloc] init];
      [mm_OthersController tScreen];
   [mm_OthersController release];


[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i did not include navigationController... OthersController is in IB..and also set as Navigation controller in tab bar